# Easy way to verify symbol changes in nm report

Tags: c, gcc, binary, symbols, nm

I am compiling my library(C programing) using Suse `gcc` compiler and then I am generating `nm` report of that library. I have to compare that nm report with the previous version library to check what are the symbols are present and not present in current version library.

```
nm libxxx0.1.a > nm_0.1.txt
nm libxxx0.2.a > nm_0.2.txt
```

Now I am just comparing `nm_0.1.txt` and `nm_0.2.txt` files with some text compare tool. Along with that symbol differences, I am getting offset differences also. I dont worry about offset differences.

Is there any command(in windows or suse) available to highlight only the symbol differences in a nm report, in easy way.

Note : Generated nm report will be very big. Manually opening that text file and using some tool to delete first column of that nm report is not an easy task for that big nm file.

Comment: For SUSE, take a look at `diff` (`man diff`).

Comment: Pipe through unix [`cut`](http://ss64.com/bash/cut.html) command to remove the first column?

Comment: Actually, `cut` doesn't play nicely here because the first column can be blank. Maybe `nm lib.a | sed 's/.* [a-Z] \(.*\)/\1/' > symbols.txt`

Comment: @BoBTFish Actually, `nm libxxx0.1.a | cut -c20-` works fine.

Comment: Good point. It's probably going to be a lot faster than regex for veeery large files as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for Linux. You must first prepare and sort your nm output

```
nm -g libxxx0.1.a | awk '{print $3}' | sort -u >nm_0.1.txt
nm -g libxxx0.2.a | awk '{print $3}' | sort -u >nm_0.2.txt
```

If you are interested in *all* symbols, leave out `-g` and use `cut` instead of `awk`

```
nm libxxx0.1.a | cut -c20- | sort -u >nm_0.1.txt
nm libxxx0.2.a | cut -c20- | sort -u >nm_0.2.txt
```

Then you can show the differences with `diff`

```
diff -U0 nm_0.1.txt nm_0.2.txt
```

or `comm`

```
comm -3 nm_0.1.txt nm_0.2.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work nicely, as the first column can be blank, so you end up with some completely blank lines.

Comment: @BoBTFish The rows without address are undefined or weak symbols. I guess, these aren't relevant here. Anyway, answer updated.